# How to access a shared folder on Windows XP (advanced file share)

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, permissions, network-shares, user-accounts

Information:
Server name: HSERVER (Windows XP SP3 Professional)
PC name: UPC (Windows 7 x64 SP1 Professional)

I have a folder, shared in Windows XP, with the advanced file sharing.
Permissions have been set (at the permission dialog, there is a user added. HSERVER/adminuser).

But... when I want to access this share, Windows 7 tells me: "You do not have permission to access \HSERVER\share. Contact your...".

So how do I share a folder properly?
If I share a folder in Windows 7, it would just ask for my (the one and only user) account's user/password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The answer](http://r3dux.org/2009/07/how-to-force-windows-to-forget-a-network-share-password/)

Simply use this command (ignore the "its in use"):
`net use Z: \\ETHERNET_BD\Code MyClevahPass123 /user:bob`

Answer (score 2):

What is the permission on the share?  Everyone Full Control?  And then the file permission?  Is that what has been assigned to HSERVER/adminuser?  What file permission does HSERVER/adminuser

Are you connecting from Win 7 as username adminuser?

Typically, if no domain to mannge accounts, you would set up a user name on HSERVER that is the same as your user name on UPC passwords would need to match.

So user account on both systems with same passowrd.  Whatever you use on UPC must be duplcuated on HSERVER.

Once that is in place, then share and file permissions come into play

Comment: "Everyone" got no permissions. TI tried adding a new user with the same name. The new user got "Full Access"... but I still get the very same error message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to authenticate your self as the user of the computer you are connecting to

User: \HSERVER\user

Password: * * * * *

Then you inherit that user's permissions.. otherwise you are just connecting as a guest and you have very few permissions

Comment: Uhm, I think the User part of your answer is a bit malformed. What do you mean? HOW am I supposed to type this? Where?